# Set of efficient 3D intersection algorithms

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d, intersection

Anyone knows a source, website where I can get some good implementations of 3D intersection algorithms, like

- intersection of sphere and sphere
- sphere/ellipsoid
- sphere/cuboid
- ellipsoid/ellipsoid
- ellipsoid/cuboid
- cuboid/cuboid
- sphere/ray
- ellipsoid/ray
- cuboid/ray
- triangle/ray
- quad/ray
- triangle/triangle
- quad/quad

Comment: I bet some of the Quake source code would have something along these lines.

Comment: Don't have a reference site, but you might want to add [GJK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) to your list.  Video describing GJK can be found [here](http://mollyrocket.com/9441)

Comment: The ONLY and BEST source for such things is the Wild Magic Library by Dave Eberly http://www.geometrictools.com

Answer (score 48, accepted):

http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html.

It's a huge matrix of algorithms that calculate intersections between various types of objects.  Excellent resource.

Comment: +1, good link.  But notice he also mentions `Real Time Collision Detection` as a 'definitive source' on the subject.  Depends on how much detail you want/need, I guess.

Comment: Actually, that page links to several other things mentioned here, RTCD, Gems, etc.  It's just a large maintained collection of references.

Answer (score 10):

Not really a website, but this book [Real-Time Collision Detection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607323) is well worth it for what you are looking for.

Comment: It's a good book.  The only problem is that it has so much math in it!

Comment: Right.  I was going for the tongue-in-cheek "there's so much math in this math book!" type comment.  I should probably avoid trying to be funny until after I've had a few cups of coffee in the morning.

Comment: He wants to do intersections between ellipsoids. The general solution to that is a 4th order curve in R3 - it requires math :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Graphics Gems](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/) is a good place to look for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put Eberly's [Game Engine Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122290631) on your bookshelf. It has detailed algorithms and discussion for each of the intersections you've listed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing raytracing, then asking at ompf.org and looking through the RTNews archives might help. In any case, it depends on what you're going to use these for.

Answer (score -1):

The source code for the POVRay ray tracer has some implementations that may be of use.